# Сan't decrement the values of sides

Tags: python

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self,s1,s2,s3,s4):
            self.side1 = s1
            self.side2 = s2
            self.side3 = s3
            self.side4 = s4

    def calculate_perimetr(self):
        return self.side1*self.side2*self.side3*self.side4
        
    def change_size(self,n):
        if n > 0 :
            self.side1 += n
            self.side2 += n
            self.side3 += n
            self.side4 += n
            print("Up")

        else:
            self.side1 -=n
            self.side2 -= n
            self.side3 -= n
            self.side4 -= n
            print("Down")


square1 = Square(10,10,10,10)
square1.change_size(-2)

print(square1.side1, square1.side2 ,square1.side3, square1.side4)
```

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  What is your question?

Comment: The perimeter of a rectangle is the sum of its sides and not the product

Comment: @SirajAlam If the "question" consists of some random code and an incomprehensible title, i don't really care. And it's a good way to make them prepare their next question better.

Comment: You don't need to store the lengths of the four sides individually. It's a square: when are the 4 values ever going to be *different*?

Comment: @SirajAlam How am I supposed to direct them towards anything if they can't even state what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class represents a square then all 4 sides are, by definition, equal. So let's assume that it's a rectangle. Then:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.dimensions = [a, b, c, d]
    def perimiter(self):
        return sum(self.dimensions)
    def change_size(self, n):
        if n != 0:
            self.dimensions = [x+n for x in self.dimensions]
            print('Up' if n > 0 else 'Down')

s = Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10)
print(s.perimiter())
s.change_size(5)
print(s.perimiter())
s.change_size(-5)
print(s.perimiter())
```

**Output:**

```
40
Up
60
Down
40
```

Answer (score -1):

From looking over your codes, it seems like you want to decrement the value on passing -ve values. But when you do a subtraction on a negative value, it eventually sums up. So just change your logic like that.

```py
    def change_size(self,n):
        self.side1 += n
        self.side2 += n
        self.side3 += n
        self.side4 += n
        if n > 0 :
            print("Up")
        else:
            print("Down")
```